# Apache mod-rewrite recursive loop

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having loop problems with my rewrite rule using mod-rewrite on Apache conf file.

I have this rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^createRoom/?$ /createRoom.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^deleteRoom/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /deleteRoom.php?session=$1 [NC,L]
```

The first works fine, but the second have problems.
I want to redirect example.com/api/deleteRoom/79a to example.com/api/deleteRoom.php?session=79a

I've tried so many things that I found but nothing solve the problem.
Someone could help me?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

I just tested on my localhost and it work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase  /
    RewriteRule ^createRoom/?$ /test.php [NC,L] 
    RewriteRule ^deleteRoom/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /test.php?session=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

test.php is very simple

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```